# Python Maya export Animation Values Script

Tags: python, maya

I want to write my animation values in a text File and read them out so I need a way to link those values to rotate start and rotate to my export and import function.

```
def animation():

    selectionList =  cmds.ls(selection=True , l = True )
    #slider = cmds.intSliderGrp("frames", visible=True, field=True, min=1, max=5000, value=200, step=1 )

    if len(selectionList) >=1:

        startTime = cmds.playbackOptions( query=True, minTime=True)
        endTime = cmds.playbackOptions( query=True, maxTime=True)

        startValue = cmds.intSliderGrp(rotStart, q= True,value =True)
        endValue = cmds.intSliderGrp(rotEnd, q= True,value =True)

        for objectName in selectionList:

            #objectTypeResult = cmds.objectType( objectName )

            #print '%s type: %s' % ( objectName, objectTypeResult )

            cmds.cutKey( objectName, time=(startTime, endTime), attribute='rotateY')# remove prevouis Keys and gets rotatye Y

            cmds.setKeyframe( objectName, time=startTime, attribute='rotateY', value=startValue)#value of key startime
            cmds.setKeyframe( objectName, time=endTime, attribute='rotateY', value=endValue)


def exportToTxtFile (): # export function

    global presetNameStartStr
    global presetNameEndStr

    filePath = cmds.fileDialog2(dialogStyle=2, fm=1)
    print filePath

    fileHandle = open(filePath[0],'w')
    fileHandle.write(presetNameStartStr)
    fileHandle.write("This is a .txt file")
    fileHandle.write(presetNameEndStr)
    fileHandle.close()

def importFromTxtFile (): # import function

    global presetNameStartStr
    global presetNameEndStr

    extensionLimitation = "Maya Files (*.txt)"
    filePath = cmds.fileDialog2(fileFilter = extensionLimitation, dialogStyle=2, fm=4)
    fileHandle = open(filePath[0],'r')
    presetString = fileHandle.read()
    fileHandle.close()
    print presetString

    splitPresetList = string.split(s = presetString, sep = presetNameStartStr)

    del splitPresetList[0]

    for i in splitPresetList:
        endPos = string.find(i,presetNameEndStr)
        namePreset = i[:endPos]
        print namePreset
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for you with json, I think it is way easier than using txt file.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import json

#store
def saveJson(path, data):
    with open(path, 'w') as outfile:
      json.dump(data, outfile)

#load
def loadJson(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
        return data
# list of objects
objectNames = ['pSphere1']
# list of attributes
attributes = ['rotateY']
# dictionary to store data
data = {}
# this maya path for data defined by your setProject
path = cmds.workspace(expandName = 'data')
# i like to put json as extension but you can put any extension you want or even none
filename = 'attributes.json'
fullpath = path + '/' + filename

# beginning the storage
for o in objectNames:
    for attr in attributes:
        # all the time value
        frames = cmds.keyframe(o, q=1, at=attr)
        # all the attribute value associated
        values = cmds.keyframe(o, q=1, at=attr, valueChange=True)
        # store it in the dictionary with key 'objectName.attribute'
        data['{}.{}'.format(o, attr)]=zip(frames, values)
        # clear the keys on the object
        cmds.cutKey( o, attribute=attr, option="keys") 

# save the file data
saveJson(fullpath, data)

# ============================================================
# LOAD DATA BACK
# =============================================================

# load the dictionary back
new_data = loadJson(fullpath)
# set values again
for k, v in new_data.iteritems():
    for t, x in v:
        o, a = k.split('.')
        cmds.setKeyframe( o, time=t, attribute=a, value=x)
```